# spark setCassandraConf is not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, databricks, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using  .setCassandraConf(c_options_conf) to set sparkSession to connect cassandra cluster as show below.

Working fine:

```
 val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("DatabaseMigrationUtility")
      .config("spark.master",devProps.getString("deploymentMaster"))
      .getOrCreate()
                .setCassandraConf(c_options_conf)
```

If I save table using dataframe writer object as below it is pointing to the configured cluster and saving in Cassandra perfectly fine as below

```
 writeDfToCassandra(o_vals_df, key_space , "model_vals"); //working fine using o_vals_df.
```

But if say as below it is pointing to localhost instead of cassandra cluster and failing to save.

Not working:

```
import spark.implicits._
val sc = spark.sparkContext

val audit_df = sc.parallelize(Seq(LogCaseClass(columnFamilyName, status,
      error_msg,currentDate,currentTimeStamp, updated_user))).saveToCassandra(keyspace, columnFamilyName);
```

It is throwing error as it is trying connect localhost.

Error:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
            at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
```

What is wrong here? Why it is pointing to default localhost even though sparkSession set to cassandra cluster and earlier method is working fine.

Comment: @Alex Ott , sir can you help with this ?   val audit_df = sc.parallelize(Seq(LogCaseClass(columnFamilyName, status,
               error_msg,currentDate,currentTimeStamp, updated_user))).saveToCassandra(keyspace, columnFamilyName);    it is pointing to default localhost instead of saving to given cluster...but otherone is working fine as explained above. can you please help me sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set the config using two set methods of `SparkSession`, i.e.  `.config(conf)` and `.setCassandraConf(c_options_conf)` with same values like below

```
  val spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("DatabaseMigrationUtility")
        .config("spark.master",devProps.getString("deploymentMaster"))
        .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",devProps.getString("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"))
        .config("spark.executor.memory",devProps.getString("spark.executor.memory"))
        .config("spark.executor.cores",devProps.getString("spark.executor.cores"))
        .config("spark.executor.instances",devProps.getString("spark.executor.instances"))
        .config(conf)

        .getOrCreate()
        .setCassandraConf(c_options_conf)
```

Then i would work for cassandra latest api as well as RDD/DF Api.

Comment: @Alex Ott , I am trying to covert my scala code to java code. when i covert the above snippet ..SparkSession does  not have .setCassandraConf... what should i do ? Any specific dependency i need to add in my pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Setting IP via `spark.cassandra.connection.host` Spark property (not via `setCassandraConf`!) works for both RDD & DataFrames. This property could be set from command-line when submitting the job, or explicitly (example from documentation):

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.123.10")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.123.10:7077", "test", conf)
```

Take look onto [documentation for connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#preparing-sparkcontext-to-work-with-cassandra), including reference about existing [configuration properties](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md).

Comment: I tried it but not much use same error.   spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",c_hosts);
        spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port",c_portNumber.toString());
       spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username",c_userName);
       spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password",c_passwd);
       spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes" ,c_concurrent_writes.toString());

Comment: Error ::: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: default/spark.cassandra.connection.host
 at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$getConfString$2.apply(SQLConf.scala:1571)
 at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getConfString(SQLConf.scala:1571)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.get(RuntimeConfig.scala:74)
 at com.snp.utils.DbUtils$.writeDfToCassandra(DbUtils.scala:29)

Comment: I tried this too but no use                                                                                                      val conf = new SparkConf(true)    
                      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",c_hosts)
                      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port",c_portNumber.toString())
                      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username",c_userName)
                      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password",c_passwd)
                      .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes" ,c_concurrent_writes.toString())

Comment: val spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("DatabaseMigrationUtility")
        .config("spark.master",devProps.getString("deploymentMaster"))
        .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",devProps.getString("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"))
     .config("spark.executor.memory",devProps.getString("spark.executor.memory"))
        .config("spark.executor.cores",devProps.getString("spark.executor.cores"))
        .config("spark.executor.instances",devProps.getString("spark.executor.instances"))
        .config(conf)
        .getOrCreate()

Comment: If i proved only config ....df.write  wont work....if I provide only setCassandraConfig  rdd.saveToCassandra dont work hence i need to set both not sure how to handle it elegently.....